# Plot Kaplan Meier Curves after computing a Ctree object

Tags: r, classification, survival-analysis

For my PhD, to identify predictive factors of COVID-19 mortality, I computed a classification survival tree using Ctree. Here is the code used:

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)
library(party)
library(partykit)

tmodel<- ctree(Surv(time,status_cov) ~ Age + Sex + Education + Migrant.background + Income + Living.situation, data = up_training_cov,control = ctree_control(maxdepth = 3))

plot(tmodel,
     type = "simple",
     gp = gpar(fontsize = 10),
     drop_terminal = TRUE,
     tnex = 1,
     beside = FALSE,
     ymax = 1,
     ylines = TRUE,
     widths = 1,
     gap = 0.1,
     reverse = FALSE,
     id = TRUE)
```

And here is the output :
[image]

I also computed a graph with the median estimated survival time and the number of individuals in each terminal node :

[image]

I'd like to keep the graph as it is and in addition to the graph, **compute a Kaplan Meier survival curve for each terminal node and display all the survival curves for the 8 terminal nodes on the same graph with one color per terminal node** so that I can visually compare the survival curves of each group.

***Can anyone help me get the KM curves and plot them? :)***

Many thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You will get the KM curves if you remove `type = "simple"` from your `plot` call.

Obviously, your data is too big too share, so here is a reproducible example using the `cancer` data set from the survival package:

```r
library(survival)
library(party)

data('cancer')

tmodel <- ctree(Surv(time, status) ~ age + sex + ph.ecog + wt.loss, data = cancer)
```

Now if we use your exact plotting code, we get:

```r
plot(tmodel,
     type = "simple",
     gp = gpar(fontsize = 10),
     drop_terminal = TRUE,
     tnex = 1,
     beside = FALSE,
     ymax = 1,
     ylines = TRUE,
     widths = 1,
     gap = 0.1,
     reverse = FALSE,
     id = TRUE)
```

[image]

But if we remove `type = "simple"`, we get a KM curve at each leaf node

```r
plot(tmodel,
     gp = gpar(fontsize = 10),
     drop_terminal = TRUE,
     tnex = 1,
     beside = FALSE,
     ymax = 1,
     ylines = TRUE,
     widths = 1,
     gap = 0.1,
     reverse = FALSE,
     id = TRUE)
```

[image]

If you want all the KM curves on a single panel, you can do:

```r
ggsurvfit(survfit2(Surv(time, status) ~ strata(node), data = cancer))
```

[image]

If you want all the plots on a different page, you can create them separately by splitting your data according to `tmodel@get_where()`, which assigns each observation to one of the leaf nodes. Just generate a list of KM plots and draw them using patchwork:

```r
library(ggsurvfit)
library(patchwork)

cancer$node <- tmodel@get_where()

plot_list <- lapply(split(cancer, cancer$node), function(d) {
  ggsurvfit(survfit2(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, d)) +
    ggtitle(paste('Leaf node = ', d$node[1]))
})

wrap_plots(plot_list)
```

[image]

Comment: Hello @Allan Cameron, many thanks for your answer. Indeed I had the survival curves of each terminal node in this way but the problem is that I have a lot of nodes and therefore they overlap and it does not become clear. I would therefore like to have a separate graph allowing all the curves to be visualized together on the same graph and leave the classification tree with the number of subjects and the estimated survival time. Do you have a solution to "isolate" the KM curves and put them all on a single graph? Many thanks :) !

Comment: @user21637271 see my update. Is that what you mean? I would caution against having 8 lines on a single plot differentiated by, say, color - this would be difficult to interpret.

Comment: Hello @Allan Cameron, yes it's exactly what I wanted to do many thanks !! :D